# Manage different configurations on different servers

Tags: grails

We are using Grails to develop and deploy on 4 servers. Each server uses the same application but loads specific configuration such as a Camel route configuration or a Quartz configuration.
We use server IP to distinguish different xml configuration such as:

```
if (IP == '10.25.3.3') {
   import resource1.xml
} else if (IP == '10.25.3.4') {
   import resource2.xml
}
```

But as deploying on more servers or adding more configurations, we need to add more conditions or change the above code when the server IP changes.

Is there any recommended way to manage these configurations and load the configuration on different environments?

Comment: Externalized configurations. That's the key. It's even mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your replying.
I have external configurations like resource1.xml, resource2.xml for different camel configuration, all in the same application code base. 
But I try to build one war and deploy to many servers, and load specific configuration not depending on server IP, because I have to change or add IP conditions when a server IP changes or deploying to a new server.
So I want to ask if there's a way to load different configurations in different environments instead of depending on server IP?

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in a comment the use of `externalized configurations`. I'll expand on that now in a full answer.

Your application should be configurable. Meaning, any settings your application needs to function that are specific to the environment/server it's being deployed to should be based on configuration values.

These values, typically set in `Config.groovy`, should be loaded from outside the application WAR. Meaning, they aren't packaged with the application but rather are on the server the application is being deployed to. The application should load these values when it starts up and configures itself accordingly.

The [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) has an entire section dedicated to this subject and is well worth the read.

While it may seem odd, at first, to have a configuration file that is not a part of your application but I assure you this is the correct approach to solving this problem. It's a very standard devops situation.

Comment: So when I want to deploy the application to a new server, I just copy the corresponding configurations to the server, and use Config.groovy to load the configuration.
Thanks for more explanation, I'll give it a try.